VSCode Black Formatter breaks long lines, force to preserve line length
I have a long list in Python, which I would like to add as a constant to my code (50-60 words). I use Black Formatter, with the following settings.json
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}

When I save the python file, it gives a super long column with values:
STOPWORDS = [
   "hello",
    "kb",
    "following",
    "december",
    "would",
    "like",
    "could",

How could I format lists using some other setting like widht? eg. to have 10 values on a row or so?
This setting isn't working:
"python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--line-length", "120"],

